# App hangs instead of throwing exception

Tags: .net, installation, clickonce, privileges

I have a *Winform App* that I deploy with *ClickOnce* that installs and works for me(my *UserLogin*) on any system in our *Domain* but will not start up for a regular *Domain User*.

It doesn't produce **any errors** of any kind just sits there indefinitely.  It **used to work** and I am at a loss as to what changed that it doesn't work now.

**I am at a complete loss as to what to look for**.  I tried taking a *DomainUser* and elevating them to *DomainAdmin*(like me) but nothing changed.  I know this is a little vague but I am looking for any insight people might have on this.

How to Troubleshoot?
Where should I be looking?

**Anything** will be appreciated.

---

I found what is causing the "hang" I just still do not understand why.

```
            try
        {
            HUD.CurrentUserRole = new ConnectBLL.BLL.RoleAccess(HUD.CurrentUser);
            sbrHUD_SecureRole.Text += " " + HUD.CurrentUserRole.RoleDescription;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            exception.LogError(this);
        }
```

My test user, Malcolm Reynolds, does not HAVE a role returned by RoleAccess().  What I do not understand is why it is hanging there vs throwing an error.

`LogError` is an extension method that emails the exception to my Mailbox and displays the error in a more User Friendly way.

```
        public static void LogError(this Exception exception, DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm whichForm)
    {
        var fileName = GetDesktopImage(whichForm);

        SendExceptionMail(exception, fileName);

        ExceptionMessageBox box = new ExceptionMessageBox(exception);
        box.Show(whichForm);
    }

    private static void SendExceptionMail(Exception exception, String fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("WWCMAIL");
            var innerExceptionMessage = String.Empty;
            if (exception.InnerException != null)
            {
                innerExceptionMessage = exception.InnerException.Message;
            }
            var stackTrace = exception.StackTrace;
            var source = exception.Source;

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage
                {
                    From = new MailAddress("MATRIX@wwCares.org"),
                    Subject = Environment.UserName + ": MATRIX Application Error",
                    Body =
                        "***THE EXCEPTION***\n" + exception.Message + "\n\n***THE INNER EXCEPTION***\n" +
                        innerExceptionMessage + "\n\n***THE STACK TRACE***\n" + stackTrace + "\n\n***THE SOURCE***\n" + source
                };

            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(fileName);
            message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            message.To.Add("PSchaller@wwCares.org");
            message.To.Add("HDesk@wwCares.org");
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'It doesn't produce any errors of any kind just sits there indefinitely'?

Comment: Consider adding a little more info: Where/When does it hang, does it use extra assemblies, etc

Comment: Are you sure it's a permission issue like your subject implies?

Comment: @rdkleine: I mean there a not any errors generated to point me in the direction of the issue.  It starts to load the app but just sits there.  It is very hard to debug as it works fine on my system and I am the only Dev so I can't step thru it to see where it is "dying"

Comment: @Henk:  It hangs during startup, before it shows the Form.  It uses many extra assemblies.  Should I be looking at my references and setting the CopyLocal and Include(for ClickOnce)?

Comment: @Jay Riggs:  I am not sure of anything at this point but that is my hunch.  I am definitely open to possible alternatives but it was my feeling that at some point(I am leaning towards SQL) permissions are causing my pain due to the fact it works for me....I guess :(

Comment: How big is the image you are trying to email?  I would comment out the SendExceptionMail method call and see what happens.

Comment: A timeout or an exception inside SendExceptionMail could produce strange results. Again, Trace it.

Comment: @Henk: Yup, thanks I did and I now know where it is hanging(just not why).  Thanks for pointing the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paladin, you will have to diagnose it a little better. And then you might find it by yourself. So I take the question to be: "How to find out what's happening?"

1. Eliminate some probable courses. Re-install (for and by the domain user). You did not try to run what was installed for (by) another user, did you?
2. Find the (slightly hidden) install folder and verify all your assemblies are there.
3. Did the app load at all? Use TaskManager.
4. If it loads, start adding diagnostic logging with Sytem.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(). You can watch the output in [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I used a variation of your suggestion to figure out what was wrong though I still have no idea why.... :)